# An integral arising  in statistics(2)

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The integral I am interested in is:
 $$t(x)=\int_{-K}^{K}\frac{\exp(ixy)}{1+y^{2q}}dy$$

$K<\infty$, q natural number

For q=1 one can use  contour integration. 
So for K>1  we have  :

$$\pi/2-\int_{Arc}\frac{\exp(ixy)}{1+y^{2}}dy $$
Where   Arc has radius $K$

Is it correct that for K<1 this integral is:
$$-\int_{Arc}\frac{\exp(ixy)}{1+y^{2}}dy ?$$

What about K=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $K=1$ your arc passes through the pole of the function $\frac{exp(ixy)}{1+y^2} = \frac{exp(ixy)}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{y-i}-\frac{1}{y+i}\right)$, so you don't get a sensible value (the discontinuity of the integrand is asymptotically $\frac{c}{t}$ for $t$ around $0$).